# What are the current principles for turbofan nacelle air path design?

Tags: turbofan, nacelle

The Wikipedia entry for '[turbofan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbofan#Technical_discussion)' states:

> Some high bypass ratio civil turbofans use an extremely low area ratio (less than 1.01), convergent-divergent, nozzle on the bypass...

But the article doesn't give supplemental references or other background apart from working line control. Can anybody give some more information if this is the case for a lot of nacelles being built nowadays or that the majority of turbofan cowls are 'simply' converging ducts and whether or not there is a trend to go to condi-nozzles in the future?